# How to upload any type of file with PHP?

Tags: php

My code is printing "Problem uploading file". I want to upload any type of file. I have created a folder named `testupload` in the same place as my codes. It should have worked but I don't know what I missed.

```
<form action="upload.php" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    <input type="file" name="file" size="50" /> 
    <br />
    <input type="submit" value="Upload" />
</form>
```

upload.php:

```
<?php

$targetfolder = "testupload/";
$targetfolder = $targetfolder . basename($_FILES['file']['name']) ;

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $targetfolder)) {
    echo "The file ". basename($_FILES['file']['name']). " is uploaded";
} else {
    echo "Problem uploading file";
}

?>
```

Comment: Can you tell me the result of `print_r($_FILES)` just after opening PHP TAG

Comment: Try: `var_dump($_FILES['file']['error']);`

Comment: Check [move_uploaded_file()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.move-uploaded-file.php). As far as description tells me this function is for moving 'already' uploaded files. You need to use HTTP Post method to upload a file.

Comment: [name] => wel.txt [type] => text/plain [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpjAPscg [error] => 0 [size] => 5826 ) ) Problem uploading file @AayushSinha

Comment: Try removing the size attribute from your html code... @FurkOk

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell with 100% certainty - but usually this would indicate a permissions or ownership problem.

Try to change the permission to the parent directory `testupload` to 777 by using `chmod 777 ./testupload`

If this solves the problem, then tighten up the permissions - 777 wouldn't be suitable for production.

Answer (score 0):

1) Does the uploaded file make it to the tmp folder? 
2) Also try var_dump($_FILES)
3) are you getting permission problems on the target folder
4) is there anything in the http error log?

Answer (score 0):

Are the permissions for the testupload directory correct? Does the www-data user have permissions to writ